# Django '/' only homepage url error

Tags: python, django, routes

I am using Django 2.0 and now I have no idea how to make an 'empty' url for the homepage. Meaning, I want it to route for `web.com/` or `web.com`. I tried this code but it does not work:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/', include('post.urls'))
]
```

...and `post.urls`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

And the error I get when I make a request to `localhost:8000`:

> Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/
>   Using the URLconf defined in myblog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> 1. admin/
> 2. /
>
> The empty path didn't match any of these.

I did sort of find a workaround by setting `path` to an empty string `''` on both but I am not sure if it is recommended or what errors it might cause. Help is much appreciated. Thank you :-).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need "/" for Home url, just leave both the path with "".
The home url 127.0.0.1:8000/ is nevertheless is same as 127.0.0.1:8000.
This URL pattern will work for the home page.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('post.urls'))
]
```

and `posts.urls`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of references to blank URL patterns in the Django 2.0 doccumentation.

[Django 2.0 Docs URLs section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters)

Furthermore, the slash you added on 'admin/' when viewing from browser is not required. The url dispatcher will strip the trailing slashes on your URL confs, but it wont be stripped on the Web request. This means it wont find a match in your case, try localhost:8000/admin