# Django default root page stops working when I add my app to urlpatterns in urls.py

Tags: django

I am new to Django and only followed one tutorial on Visual Studio which worked fine.
Now I was trying to create another project on PyCharm and am facing the below problem.

the default Django template sets up fine in Pycharm and I see the default root/landing page when I run the project.

but the moment I add a url for my app in urls.py the default Django page stops working, although both the admin url and myapp urls work fine.

my Urlspatterns is provided below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp')), 
]
```

the moment I remove the line the default Django landing page starts working again.
I have tried searching online but was unable to find an explanation. Posting it here because I would really like to know why this happens.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running it in debug mode so you can get the traceback? It would help to know what the error is you're getting.

Comment: added screenshot to the above question

Comment: That screenshot tells you what the problem is. You need to define a URL pattern for the homepage of the site. Right now you could go to `'admin/'` or `'myapp/'` but not `''`. [Add a URL pattern for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48064315/9374673) that points to a view and see if that fixes it.

Comment: hi @MihaiChelaru, my question is, when I remove the 'myapp' url definition, then the root '/' url works, even though there is no definition available except for 'admin/' in the urlpatterns generated by the project.

it's only when I add a URL in addition to the default 'admin' when the default landing page stops working.

Comment: The answer to that is on the page itself. Just look at the screenshot in the answer below: "You are seeing this page because DEBUG=True is in your settings file and **you have not configured any URLs**. When you added that URL pattern in there the default Django homepage disappears. Add your own homepage as I described, since I presume you want to do that anyways. I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru, ok, thanks that makes sense.

do you know what to point to for "/" url to continue showing the default landing page?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, but the template for that page is called `default_urlconf.html` and for me it's found in the following path relative to the folder your Python containing the django package is located in: `Lib > site-packages > django > views > templates`. I suppose if you really want to keep this page you can add a copy of that template to your app's templates folder and create a view for it for the `''` URL path. It seems easier to create your own homepage though.

Comment: Super, thanks.. that's what I was looking for. will give it a shot.
and it was more out of curiosity because I didn't understand the behaviour, vs any real life use

Comment: Yeah, I found it interesting too to look for it and look at the code in that template. Don't know what some of those tags do myself. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This page is intended only to show that django is working properly. As soon as you add any url it is disabled.

Comment: I would expect the root / default page to stay unless specifically overridden in the urls file, otherwise it ends up displaying an error (image now added)